# How to modify external process using Python

Tags: python, debugging, memory, process

Beginner here. I am trying to figure out how to modify a running process on a linux system using Python.

Example: I have a python program that takes in as an argument a PID. My goal is to use this PID and get info about the running process with that PID. 
(1) Find where it is located in memory
(2) Where is the instruction pointer
(3) Modify the program such that the next executed instruction is something else
(4) Return the pointer back to the next legitimate instruction 
(5) Let the original process execute as it should have

I am trying to develop a POC to show how a small piece of code can be injected into a running process to just print 'hello' to stdout and not disturb the rest of the process.

I looked up trace and some other modules but they all seem to do with following the currently executing python process. Also looked at pyhook, but its mainly to trap signals from keyboards etc.. additionally, I looked up pygdb a bit.

Can anyone please point me to some modules that might be useful, or some code samples. I tried googling for "python inspect process PID" etc.. did not get anything very useful.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why Python? Your task is hard enough without that handicap.

Comment: I am a relative newbie to Python, and I like it a lot, just trying to solve an interesting problem, hopefully I'll learn a fair bit :-)

Comment: Also looked up pydbg from Paimei and Gray Hat Python. It seems pydbg is tuned for windows (will investigate more). The book is tuned for Windows systems, I primarily use a Ubuntu/mac.

Comment: "Modify the program such that the next executed instruction is something else"  Really?  Why?  And how will you get past the ownership for that other process?

Comment: @S.Lott - lets say I have root/sudo privileges. I am trying to develop some POC code. A first version will of course be a little hackish.

Comment: " A first version will of course be a little hackish".  Really.  An operating system modification like this that (a) stops a process from being scheduled, (b) breaks security to override the unwritable code page, and then (c) resumes execution is a breathtaking change to the kernel.  In Python.  "Hackerish" isn't the issue when I contemplate how complex this is going to be.

Comment: Actually the concept is some ways similar to what KSplice does where dynamic libraries are re-mapped on the fly to apply patches. At least thats my interpretation. I'm just getting off the blocks with Python here, so I guess I'll learn a lot bumping into walls and possibly finding ways around them. Do you have any ideas about a first step (1) attaching to a running process from inside python (I know I can run os.popen with gdb -a pid, but thats not really the way, is it.)

Comment: Pick a different first project for Python.  At minimum, you'll need to interface to native C code to get this done.  Learn Python first, then learn the C API.

Answer (score 0):

Also a newer python user. Can you do all these things with just the command line? If so then you could use os.system('[command]') or the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess). For example you could use the [pmap command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-find-memory-used-by-program.html) to get the memory mappings. As for 2-5 I have no experience there. Good Luck.